# telemetry data after breaching the threshold generate multiple mails until the telemetry data come under the threshold in thigsboard

Tags: thingsboard, thingsboard-gateway

this is my rule cain(https://i.stack.imgur.com/VVkmh.png)

what I require to do is after the threshold breached , the first mail needs to be generated after 30 minuets and the second mail needs to be generated until the the telemetry data come under the threshold.
how we can put time duration from the first mail to the other mail ?

Comment: i think we need to do some thing with the first mail's time series and the - second mails time series  = 30 min

Comment: I think you can use wait or sleep node in between.

Comment: first message need to generate the first time threshold breached the second mail need to generate after 30 minutes from the first mail

Answer (score 0):

You could easily solve this issue, if you only send a mail only when an alarm is created.
Like this:
[image]